# How to combine 2D animation and motion tracking?

Tags: animation, tracking, 2d

I'm trying to do a 2D animation. I'm compositing a shape on top of existing video footage, and I want a figure to follow the motion of someone in the footage.

Because this is all 2D, I don't want a 3D solve --- ideally I want to be able to create tracks in VFX->Motion Tracking and then make my figure's bones' screen coordinates directly match the position of the tracks.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Most references online are either dealing with full-on 3D camera solving, or with 2D rotoscoping. One of the latter says I can reparent rotoscoping points to the track, which is precisely what I'm looking for; but I don't seem to be able to reparent renderable objects to tracks, and besides, wouldn't reparenting a bone interfere with the way it distorts the figure?

I'm sure Blender can do this, because it can do anything. But how?

Comment: Start with a VFX type project in blender.
Do the motion tracking in a regular way.
Once you are happy with it, You assign it to an empty (Reconstruction -> Link Empty to Track).
Then you add a 2d Animation Tab to you project and in the constraints you copy transform from the empty to your grease pencil object.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! (I wish Blender functionality was more discoverable...) I'm actually using the 3D modeller, but in 2D, but the empty appears in the modeller and is locked to the current camera's screen coordinates. This is precisely what I want. If you copy that to an answer I can mark it correct!